# New list_display after list_filter enabled Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

I have been playing around with the Django admin pages and got stuck and can't seem to find a solution in the documentation. I have defined three different models: Location, RestaurantFeature and Employee. There three models are all linked to one another. This question is specific for my Employee model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantFeature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    prior_experience = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_contract = models.IntegerField()
    hourly_salary = models.FloatField()

    def _get_full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    full_name = property(_get_full_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.full_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Employees"
```

The custom admin layout which I have:

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('full_name','restaurant','prior_experience',)
    list_filter = ('restaurant',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', )
admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

This works great! The display which is defined works and so does the filter. What I would like: is a new `list_display` once the `restaurant filter` is enabled! This way more detailed information could be provided when required.

How to define a new `list_display` once the `list_filter` is applied?

**MORE CLEARER:**
The list_display now defines the full name, restaurant and prior experience. I would like these variables to change to full name, restaurant, prior experience, hour contract and hourly salary once the restaurant filter is applied! So for instance, all the employees for all the restaurants are displayed with some general information but once for instance 'McDonald's' is selected, more detailed information is provided for McDonald's employees.

Comment: This isn't clear, I'm afraid. What exactly do you mean by "a new list_display once the restaurant filter is enabled"? New in what way?

Comment: I am sorry. The `list_display` now defines the full name, restaurant and prior experience. I would like these variables to change to full name, restaurant, prior experience, hour contract and hourly salary once the restaurant filter is applied! So for instance, all the employees for all the restaurants are displayed with some general information but once for instance 'Mc Donalds' is selected, more detailed information is provided for Mc Donalds employee's.

Answer (score 0):

The ModelAdmin class defines a [`get_list_display()` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L841) that takes the request as a parameter. Conceivably you could check `request.GET` to see if it includes any filter params, then return a different list of fields from that method.